# Save files from raw to device

Tags: android, android-studio, save

I am trying to save a sound which is located in the raw folder (A .ogg file) to the devices storage, when button 1 is pressed for 1.5 seconds, and 'Okay' is pressed on a confirmation message.

I've searched for a good tutorial on how to do this, but I can't seem to find any :/

I'm very new to Android programming and I'm currently working on my first app, a soundboard. As this is my first app, I hope you can explain this simply.

Thanks in advance,

-Spickle

Comment: man you have to try something.. then we can help you

Comment: You can do something like this:
<blink>
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourRawFile);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("yourOutputDirectory");
        byte [] byteData = new byte [2048];
        int read;
        while((read = is.read(byteData)) > 0) {
            fos.write(byteData);
        }
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
</blink>